# How to find search volume of large set of Keywords (say 1 million) by Keyword planner or Adword API

Tags: seo, traffic, keyword-search, google-ads-api

I am using Keyword planner to find keywords' search volume. But when I upload a .CSV file, there is a limit of 3000 keywords.
How can I get the search volume of a large set of Keywords which I want to.
Is there any way by Adword API or somw other tool ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the AdWords API [TargetingIdeaService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/TargetingIdeaService) to get Keyword Planner data for large sets of keywords.

This will allow you to get search volume (and other metrics) for a specified list of keywords. As well as your input list of keywords you would have to specify a [requestType](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/TargetingIdeaService.RequestType) of `STATS` in you [TargetingIdeaSelector](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/TargetingIdeaService.TargetingIdeaSelector).

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please clarify few more things:

1. Can I use this API without MCC account, Developer token and client token by any way ?. 

2. If not then out of above 3 I mentioned, which are mandatory to use the API ?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Developer token, Client Id and Client Secret are all mandatory to gain access to the API

Comment: OK. I generated token and Secret. 
1. What should be the application type while generating Token ? I will be using on local PHP webserver. So Web Application  is right ? 
2. Can u give me any sample code or link where I can find how to use the API in PHP.